What does "you’d think he invented fire" mean?
In The Beekeeper (2024), Agent Verona speaks to beekeeper Adam Clay about her
brother and mother:

Verona: You’re just like my brother. He was in MARSOC, a Marine Raider.
He was killed a few years ago kicking doors. She loved him.
He’d mow the lawn and you’d think he invented fire. (CHUCKLES)

What does "you’d think he invented fire" mean?

He'd do a minor task such as mowing the lawn and the mother would act as though he were Prometheus, who had invented fire for humankind. A form of exaggeration.  The exaggeration could reveal the sister's sibling envy, or the mother's favoritism.  We do not know without the dramatic context.

The phrase "you'd think he invented fire" reflects how much the mother praised him out of love. It's an exaggerated statement, suggesting that even when her brother did something ordinary like mowing the lawn, her mother's praise made it seem extraordinary—like he invented fire.
Such exaggerations are used to add humor to the scene, highlighting her affection in a lighthearted way.
